# Android toast in Cordova App

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I am building an app with jquery mobile and corodova.
I am searching for a plugin that can be used for creating android toast notification from my app.

Had checked one named `cordova-plugin-toast` but it is showing that is only for blackberry. Link to the plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-toast

Suggest me a way to display toast.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see my answer if that works for you please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Ok. I will check it and mark it as answer.

Comment: Is this plugin available on npm?

Comment: yes it is available. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-toast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this  : cordova-plugin-x-toast (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-toast)

In your config.xml file, add
< gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-toast" source="npm" />

The usage is explained in https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-toast#4-usage

Comment: Thanks for the plugin Ajith